# Bulma inputs ignore size attribute

Tags: forms, bulma

Using Bulma v0.7.1, the `input` class causes `input="text"` controls to spread to the available column width, even when the size attribute is specified.

```
<label class="label">Short input1</label>
<input class="input" name="short_input1" type="text" size="3">
```

Example:

[image]

The [4th Commandment](https://mono.company/design-practice/the-10-commandments-of-good-form-design-on-the-web/) of Good Form Design states that text inputs should be *"sized according to their expected input"*.

How can I appropriately size text inputs using Bulma?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygx2esca/)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find how to set input width natively within Bulma, and nesting columns caused the respective labels to linewrap (and nesting didn't offer fine tune control over `<input type="text">` width).

So, I ended up [hard coding a style attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/ynw261gv/). `:/`

```
<input style="width:3em;" class="input" name="inp1" type="text"  placeholder="123">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Bulma does not have that feature yet.
You can however use the **onkeypress** event:

```
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Type your Name" name="short_input1" value='' onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 3) * 8) + 'px';">
```

Note: this solution only works when every character is exactly 8px wide.
Check out my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldi/ycntarjs/28/).

Comment: Yeah, I scoured the docs and was surprised not to see a native (to Bulma) way of controlling width of input-texts.   Added a [bug report](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1955) yesterday.   If I have to add style attributes to get the size where I need, I'll go that route.. really need the sizes to be set when the form is first opened as opposed to after typing.

Comment: @acoder You can restrict the character limit and use a certain size for the column of the input field.

Comment: Just posted that in the comment above yours (see my edited fiddle).  I may also be able to edit Bulma's source css, to remove `.input,
.textarea { max-width: 100%; width: 100%; }`, but I'm concerned this might break mobile layouts.

Comment: @acoder I don't recommend messing up with Bulma Core CSS because as you said it will mess up responsiveness. :D